# Job for ssh.service failed because the control process exited with error code

Tags: ssh, openssh

I was trying to install ssh service and I did with this command: `sudo apt install openssh-server` and I tried to start it with this command: `sudo systemctl start ssh` but it gives me that error: `Job for ssh.service failed because the control process exited with error code. See "systemctl status ssh.service" and "journalctl -xeu ssh.service" for details.` if someone know a solution please help. Thanks

Comment: Please run the suggested commands and post the results into your question using the [edit] button

Comment: Which distro and version of Linux are you using?

Comment: sudo systemctl restart sshd